# How to create unique template reference variables

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular9

I want to do dynamic form validation. I created **unique name attribute** but I don't know how to create ngModel's dynamic template reference variable. Because of the that I'm getting some issues in the valdation.

**My code**

````
<ng-container *ngFor="let singleLocation of model.LocationArr; let i = index">                            
<div class="col-xl-5">
  <label style="font-weight: 700;">License Location</label>
  <span style="color:#F6566B;">*</span>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="formcontrol"name="unq{{singleLocation}}" 
    [(ngModel)]="singleLocation.location" #location1="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && location1.invalid }"
    required ngx-google-places-autocomplete [options]='option'
    #placesRef="ngx-places" (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)">
    <div *ngIf="f.submitted && location1.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="location1.errors.required">License Location is required</div>
     </div>
 </div>
</ng-container>```
````

Comment: Are you using ReactiveForms ?

Comment: No template driven form.

Comment: It's hard to give you a concrete answer without having a look at your corresponding ts file.
I'd suggest you using the ngOnChanges method to perform your  validation, it will be called on every change to the ngModel var.
However since your Template file looks not really great structured you might be faster if you look at angular tutorials and try to reimplement their dynamic forms.